# C# Outlook 2010 get FULL Global Address List Inforamtion

Tags: c#, outlook, exchange-server

I have a some problem - I need to receive FULL global address list from outlook 2010 on my machine.
I mean all field:

Title,"First Name","Middle Name","Last Name","Suffix","Company","Department","Job Title","Business Street","Business Street 2","Business Street 3","Business City","Business State","Business Postal Code","Business Country/Region","Home Street","Home

If I trying export GAL from outlook I can get this list. But How I can do this via C#?

I'm trying like this:

```
        Application oApp = new Application();
        NameSpace oNS = oApp.GetNamespace("mapi");
        oNS.Logon("Name", "Pass", false, true);
        AddressLists oDLs = oNS.AddressLists;
        AddressList oGal = oDLs["Global Address List"];            
        string sDL = "TestDL";
        AddressEntries oEntries = oGal.AddressEntries;
        AddressEntry oDL = oEntries[sDL];    
        oEntries = oDL.Members;
        AddressEntry oEntry = default(AddressEntry);    
        for (i = 1; i <= oGal.AddressEntries.Count ; i++  )
        {
            oEntry = oGal.AddressEntries[i];
            //listBox1.Items.Add(oEntry.Name);
        }
```

But every AddressEntries[i] contain only Name, Email and nothin else.

Answer (score 1):

Use `AddressEntry.PropertyAccessor` to retrieve any available MAPI property.

E.g. to retrieve the fist name, retrieve the `PR_GIVEN_NAME_W` property (= `0x3A06001F`).
Have a look at the address book objects with [MFCMAPI](https://github.com/stephenegriffin/mfcmapi) or [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy) (I am its author) to figure out what is available and what the property tags are.

```
givenName = AddressEntry.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3A06001F")
```

Comment: Sorry, can you elaborate with just a bit of code, how to use PR_GIVEN_NAME_W. I don't even know where to use it.

Comment: Yeh, thanks, i had tried this, but i got `The property "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3A06001F" is unknown or cannot be found.`

Comment: But with this proptag - `0x800F101E` it works. I got array of strings. Only i don't understand any value from there.

Comment: Did you look at that GAL object in OutlookSpy to see what is available? Click IAddrBook, Ope nRoot Container, GetHierarchyTable, etc. to drill down to any entry.